# Java Web Application - Servlet Problem

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat

I have servlet  that does the following:

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        request.getAttribute("username");
        request.getAttribute("password");
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        LoginManager lm = new LoginManager(username.trim(), password.trim());
```

Whenever I reach the last tomcat apache "crashes" with the following error message:

```
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception

root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/rpc/ServiceException
    servlets.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:20)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1666)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1511)
    servlets.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:20)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Please Help
Thanks!

When including jaxrpc.jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder I get following error:

root cause

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/axis/AxisFault
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native
>   Method)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
>     java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2778)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1139)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1511)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native
>   Method)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
>     java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2778)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1139)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1511)
>     servlets.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:20)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.axis.AxisFault
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1666)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1511)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native
>   Method)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
>     java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2778)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1139)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1511)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native
>   Method)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
>     java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2778)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1139)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1511)
>     servlets.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:20)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

Comment: You are missing a jar file. You can find which jar file should be in your classpath by looking at this list: http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException

Comment: http://findjar.com/class/javax/xml/rpc/ServiceException.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomcat version and JDK / JRE version would be helpful.

It looks like your webapp is missing some required jars from WEB-INF/lib; in particular the jaxrpc jar.

Answer (score 1):

The server tells you that you're missing a library, the one that contains `javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException`.

However, the code you gave don't seem to use this class, so I think your problem isn't related to your Servlet.

Comment: I'm assuming that the LoginManager has a dependency on jaxrpc.

Comment: import javax.xml.rpc.*;

public class LoginManager {

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me as though somewhere along the line there's an [Apache Axis](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/) dependency which needs to be addressed in your app's build path. Chances are, this is in the error handling for your JAXRPC calls.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting the 2nd exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/axis/AxisFault

It's because you've included `javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException`. I'm assuming you're using Axis else you're wouldn't be getting `AxisFault`. There are some jars that are missing.

If you want `AxisFault` to disappear, copy the `axis.jar` (assuming you're running the old axis 1) to the `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Answer (score -1):

sorry for the late reply..this may help someone in future..

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException
 It says it cant found the javax.xml.rpc jar.
Please add the dependency to your POM file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>  javax.xml.rpc  </groupId>
    <artifactId>  javax.xml.rpc-api  </artifactId>
    <version>  1.1.1  </version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).