# Can we use existing Servlets in the Spring MVC project source, If yes then how t configure my web.xml file

Tags: spring, servlets

As I am upgrading  normal  JSP, Servlet java application with Spring web MVC framework. In Stage 1  of the project I would like to reuse the UI part of the code which has JSP's and Servlets. So currently I am mixing the concept of normal Servlets and Spring MVC Dispatcherservlet configuration.
 I need help on wether its possible ?
Secondly how the request is handled?
I am getting the below exception when I access the URL: domain/projectname/quoteentry

```
Jun 19, 2014 4:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet QuoteEntry
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1664)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1509)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2493)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2803)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:817)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:163)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:556)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:402)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:310)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:575)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1555)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: try to add this library to web-inf/lib

take a look:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854586/java-web-application-servlet-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are working with maven add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrpc</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```